# Small Problem with WPF XBAP

Tags: wpf, xbap

Sometimes my XBAP application gives this error. Did someone else had this problem?

System.InvalidOperationException: No further operations are possible with this instance.

This is on https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=496484

Complete stack

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No further operations are possible with this instance.

at System.Deployment.Application.InPlaceHostingManager.AssertState(State validState)
at System.Deployment.Application.InPlaceHostingManager.Execute()
at MS.Internal.AppModel.XappLauncherApp.ExecuteDownloadedApplication()
at System.Windows.Interop.DocObjHost.RunApplication(ApplicationRunner runner)
at MS.Internal.AppModel.XappLauncherApp.XappLauncherApp_Exit(Object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Application.OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Application.DoShutdown()
at System.Windows.Application.ShutdownImpl()
at System.Windows.Application.ShutdownCallback(Object arg)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error stopped happening they release the final stable .Net Framework 4.0 .

This was problably caused by some bug in the Beta that I was using.